# What means the error "already purchased" when buying a Consumable item with Unity IAP?

Tags: unity, google-play-services, in-app-purchase

I'm facing an issue related to Unity IAP with consumable items. If I try to purchase one it shows: "Item already purchased" with this

> log- 
>   onIabPurchaseFinished: false 
>   Unable to buy item (response: 7:Item Already Owned)

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: I seriously doubt it.

Comment: I exactly didn't get how to get "Finish Transition" callback in unity iap

Comment: If the answer provided helped you, please upvote and accept it so other people know, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Unity IAP, but as the log states, a consumable item *"has already been purchased"*. The log tells you `onIabPurchaseFinished: false`. This means that the in app puchase didn't finish(because apparently you *already* purchased it). It also tell you `Unable to buy item (response: 7:Item Already Owned)`, so the cause is: you already own the item.

To fix the problem, you need to call `FinishTransaction` to *consume* the consumable. That way Google knows the user did get his reward, and can complete the transaction successfully.

Comment: I think the thrust of the question is that, for a consumable item, we would expect to be able to purchase it multiple times. But maybe the item has been misconfigured in some way, so it's not being treated as consumable? Or is there another step the game needs to take to signal that it's now safe to purchase a second copy (in case there are some consumables with a minumum time between purchases, or that can't be stockpiled and must be used before re-buying, etc...)?

Comment: I'd recommend [edit]ing this just to clarify what you mean by "consume". Presumably you don't mean "use ingame"; maybe "complete the transaction" would be a better phrase to use?